# Remove cell with a length, lower than 8 characters

Tags: excel, vba

I have some spreadsheets with a couple thousand rows. I'd like a macro that will count the number of characters in the cells in the 'A' column and delete the row if it's less than 8 characters.

Comment: What have you tried so far? (Please edit your question with this info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please run this code on Excel

```
Sub DelRows()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = LR To 1 Step -1
    If Len(Range("A" & i).Value) < 8 Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Lastrow As Long, Row As Long

        'Loop sheets
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

            With ws
                'Find Last row of column A in sheet ws
                Lastrow = .cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                'Loop rows from bottom to top
                For Row = Lastrow To 1 Step -1

                    'Check value lenght
                    If Len(.Range("A" & Row).Value) > 8 Then
                        .Rows(Row).Delete
                    End If

                Next Row

            End With

        Next ws

End Sub
```